# Loading module with @use in SASS imported file causes SassError: Undefined variable

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I have `styles.scss` file which loads variables from `variables.scss` and pass them to all imported stylesheets ([according to docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#:%7E:text=variables%20that%20were%20defined%20before%20the%C2%A0%40import%20(including%20from%20other%20%40imports)%20are%20available%20in%20the%20imported%C2%A0stylesheet.))

```scss
// style.scss
@use "variables" as *;

@import "test";
```

```scss
// variables.scss
$body-color: red;
```

If I use simple `_tests.scss` then it works fine.

```scss
// _tests.scss
body {
    color: $body-color;
}
```

But when I try to use other modules inside imported file, I get an error:

```scss
// _tests.scss
@use "sass:math"; // this line causes "Undefined variable" error

body {
    color: $body-color;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?